# legend repeated and appeared outside the figure in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, jupyter-notebook

I wondered why legend attribute not working properly

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(decoded_imgsr[777600:864000],'r',label="conv_decoded_img1")
#plt.axis([10000,10200,-1250,0]) 
#fig.suptitle('conv_decoded_img1', fontsize=20)
plt.xlabel('time', fontsize=18)
plt.ylabel('amplitude', fontsize=16)
plt.legend(loc="upper right")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: What is `decoded_imgsr` ?

Comment: decoded_imgsr is an array of (1209600, 200) elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following for your legend:

plt.legend(['conv_decoded'],loc="upper right")